# Invoking a function with a click event in form (VB)

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio

I am building a form to convert a number score into a letter grade and need to invoke a function that is called when I click on the "btnCalc" button.  The input field on the form is titled "txtScore" and the output field is "txtGrade".

The code below isn't working and I'm also getting this error: "
'txtScore' is ambiguous because multiple kinds of members with this name exist in class"

I'm not sure what could be wrong, I've gone through a lot tutorials and documentation but can't seem to resolve.  Would someone be able to help?

```
Public Class GradeForma

Dim txtScore = Math.Round(txtScore)

Public Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    GetLetterGrade(txtScore)
End Sub

Public Function GetLetterGrade(ByVal dblGrade As Double) As String
    If txtScore <= 59 Then
        txtGrade.Text = "F"
    ElseIf txtScore <= 69 Then
        txtGrade.Text = "D"
    ElseIf txtScore <= 79 Then
        txtGrade.Text = "C"
    ElseIf txtScore <= 89 Then
        txtGrade.Text = "B"
    ElseIf txtScore <= 100 Then
        txtGrade.Text = "A"
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: change `txtScore` to another unique name as it's already used elsewhere in the class. Also, avoid doing `Dim txtScore` as `txtScore` in this case is of type `Object`. not good habit to get into. rather since `Math.Round` returns a double or a decimal we can do `Dim result As Double = Math.Round(txtScore)` or `Dim result As Decimal = Math.Round(txtScore)`

Comment: I susoect you have a TextBox named `txtScore`  dont use the same name for a local variable....just like the error message is telling you.  Then please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: As @Aominè states, you have a variable named txtScore, but also you have named a TextBox on the form "txtScore".  Both of these are members of the same class - so this is actually a very informative message and describes the problem correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass parameters around for this example, just pull out the value from txtScore when you need it in GetLetterGrade().  You likely don't need a class level variable at all - as you maybe don't need to hold onto the result?

```
Public Class GradeForma

    Public Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
        GetLetterGrade()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetLetterGrade() As String

        Dim dblResult as Double = Math.Round(txtScore)

        If dblResult <= 59 Then
            txtGrade.Text = "F"
        ElseIf dblResult <= 69 Then
            txtGrade.Text = "D"
        ElseIf dblResult <= 79 Then
            txtGrade.Text = "C"
        ElseIf dblResult <= 89 Then
            txtGrade.Text = "B"
        ElseIf dblResult <= 100 Then
            txtGrade.Text = "A"
        End If

    End Function
```